# Approval workflow with email notifications using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval

I have a requisition order form created with Infopath and using SharePoint 2013 on prem and I want that a user that submits the form for approval will choose the approver from a drop-down list and sends an email to the approver to either approve or reject the order.

P.S. the approver can be anyone not the same person, and there where I am stuck!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Choice column for the Approver field, you can create a SharePoint 2013 workflow using SharePoint Designer and then use the Approver field in the **Assign a task** action.

Please see a sample workflow here:
[image]

In this scenario, the Choice column values will be converted to strings and then be identified as usernames, so we need to write the users’ **Display Names** (instead of Account Names) as column values.
[image]